# As a ghostwriter, can I edit my author's Scrivener file?

Tags: scrivener, ghostwriter

Has anyone had experience editing someone's private Scrivener files from offsite? Or, can you conceptualize what I'm asking here and see a solution from your experience with the scrivener tool?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot Scrivener-specific experience.

You can, subject to being careful not to both edit the same file at the same time. I don't think Scrivener has file locking/version control that way for collaboration (I'm not 100% sure about that).

You shouldn't do it for 2 reasons

**1. Version Control**

How do you know what you've changed and maybe you would prefer to revert to an earlier version.

I'm a fan of keeping backups of drafts and changing a copy of a draft. That way you know when and how things have changed on a project.

There is something great about seeing who's changed what. This can be done in

- Google Docs,
- Microsoft Word (file swapping and possibly online),
- or search for Scrivener + Git.  https://nocategories.net/ephemera/git-scrivener is not hard to set up but a little bit technical.

I also know writer-teams who use wiki software so they have inbuilt version control. One chapter per wiki article and their research notes are there too.

**2. Collaboration**

Seriously consider Google Docs for live collaboration. If you don't write simultaneously then never mind that.

**3. Backups and corruption**

Editing the Scrivener bundles directly *should* work, but Murphy is looking over your shoulder. It will eventually bite you, so have regular backups off-site as well.

If the Author you're ghost-writing for is absolutely non-technical I recommend editing chapters they've finished with. In which case you should be able to deliver files named as, *Chapter-01-edited*. So your files are noticeably different from the originals.